# AVAudioPCMBuffer - read(into buffer: AVAudioPCMBuffer) memory crash? (buffer overflow)

Tags: ios, swift, buffer, avfoundation, avaudiopcmbuffer

The following code works for audio files of short duration on all my devices (iPhone, Apple Watch, Simulator):

`let file = try! AVAudioFile(forReading: url!)
 let format = AVAudioFormat(commonFormat: .pcmFormatFloat32, sampleRate:       file.fileFormat.sampleRate, channels: file.fileFormat.channelCount,  interleaved: false)
let buf = AVAudioPCMBuffer(pcmFormat: format!, frameCapacity: UInt32(file.length))
try! file.read(into: buf!)`

The crash occurs at `try! file.read(into: buf!)`
However trying to read a 5 min for example long audio file is causing a crash running on my Apple Watch (though works on the Apple Watch Simulator). With `Program ended with exit code: 0`.

Watching the debug tools, obviously this process is a lot more taxing on the Apple Watch than an iPhone. I've tried to run it on different threads, background, etc to no avail.

I know I could send the buffer to the iPhone for processing, however I'd like to see (even if it takes a little longer) if I can read into the buffer strictly from the watch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

5 minutes of mono LPCM float32 audio at 44.1kHz would be 5*60*44100*4 bytes, or about 53MB. Double that for stereo. I'm don't know what the watch's memory limits are, but I think you're exceeding them.

Comment: Yes its actually 2 Channel Audio, in the debugger the watch hits about 70-80mb of memory usage, then crashes. Is there anyway I could mitigate the load on the Apple Watch?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Do you really need to load 5 minutes of audio at once? Or decompress it?

Comment: I'm loading the buffer into —  readFile.arrayValues = Array(UnsafeBufferPointer(start: buf!.floatChannelData?[0], count:Int(buf!.frameLength))) from there I process the points to create an audio waveform. I have to do it this way, because easier ways to do such are not available frameworks on watchOS.

Comment: Not all the audio samples have to be present in memory at the same time to draw a decent looking waveform, you could process the audio file in small pieces.